# Comentário aninhado no C#

Tags: c#, sintaxe, comentários

Como escrever `/*...*/` dentro de um comentário `/*...*/` no C#?

Já tentei de tudo coloquei entre parênteses, entre aspas e nada.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 1):

Algumas linguagens possuem alguma facilidade para isto na sintaxe, mas C# não, não tem como fazer porque é ambíguo sobre o fechamento do comentário, precisaria de uma sintaxe que permite usar uma forma diferente e ter níveis diferentes de comentários.

Na verdade, até tem, que é o comentário *inline* (`//`) que pode estar dentro do comentário de bloco, ainda que não seja o que deseja.

Então não crie essa situação, quase nunca é necessário de fato, sempre tem uma solução.

Quase sempre acontece quando tem um comentário de bloco normal e usa um novo bloco como um *comment out*. Esse caso pode ser mais interessante usar um recurso de IDE que comenta tudo com `//` ou cuidadosamente deixar o bloco de comentário de fora. Em alguns casos pode ser interessante usar uma diretiva `#if` para impedir a execução de uma parte do código.